# .htaccess questions

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Say I have the following .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} name=value [NC]
RewriteRule ^image01.gif$ http://www.domain.tld/images/partner/image01.gif [NC,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} name=value [NC]
RewriteRule ^image02.gif$ http://www.domain.tld/images/partner/image02.gif [NC,QSA]
```

What do `NC` and `QSA` mean?

Also, instead of repeating the same `RewriteCond` twice is there to use it just once and have it apply to both `RewriteRule`s?

Finally, if the above .htaccess is located at http://www.domain.tld/images/ why doesn't a RewriteRule like this work?:

`RewriteRule ^image02.gif$ /images/partner/image02.gif [NC,QSA]`

Or maybe this?:

`RewriteRule ^image02.gif$ partner/image02.gif [NC,QSA]`

Answer (score 4):

The square bracket options are documented in the [RewriteRule manual page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule):

'nocase|NC' (no case):

> This makes the Pattern case-insensitive, ignoring difference
>   between 'A-Z' and 'a-z' when Pattern is matched against the current URL.

'qsappend|QSA' (query string append):

> This flag forces the rewrite engine to append a query string part
>   of the substitution string to the
>   existing string, instead of replacing
>   it. Use this when you want to add more
>   data to the query string via a rewrite
>   rule.

---

As far as I know, the [RewriteCond directives](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) affect the RewriteRule they precede. If you were setting rules in the main confing file you could write the common directives in a file and [include](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/core.html#include) it several times but that's not an option in `.htaccess` files, sorry.

---

Your directive works for me, although you probably mean this:

```
RewriteRule ^image02\.gif$ /images/partner/image02.gif [NC,QSA]
```

How are you testing it exactly?

Answer (score 1):

NC is for No Case, meaning it can be upper or lower case and it will take you to the same page.

QSA is for query string append. Not really sure on this one, however a quick search http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html sheds a bit more light on this one.